# Verify product availability by SKU

Tags: magento-2.1, module, sku

I've a form in which I'm using ajax to get product sku and quantity from user.

I successfully got those entered data in form to my custom module's controller.

Now I need to verify that user's entered value with actual product sku in my site.

How can I do that inside my controller's `execute()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in your controller class :

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    $this->_product = $product;
}

public function execute()
{ 
   $sku = 'your_sku';
   if($this->_product->getIdBySku($sku)) {
     echo 'product exist';    
   }
}
```